# different behavior in Python when creating set from constructor or literal

Tags: python, set

I am trying to create a Set structure in Python by using code below:

```
a = set ([1,2,3])
print (a)
a ={1,2,3}
print (a)
a = {'FG'}
print (a)
a = set('FG')
print (a)
```

output:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{'FG'}
{'F', 'G'}
```

while the set creation with a list of numbers leads to the same result using the two options,
I see that if the input type is a String the result that I expect is the second, i.e. create a set of characters, while the first result seems to ignore that a string is a sequence of characters, therefore I am confused.

Comment: Did you note that ```set(['FG'])``` outputs ```{'FG'}``` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `set()` constructor takes an iterable as an argument and will create a set of each unique item in that iterable.  In this case a string **IS** the iterable, so you are seeing a set composed of each character in the string.

To get a set strings, places the strings in a list or tuple.

```py
set(['abc', 'efg'])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `a = {'FG'}`, you define the set with one single element which is the string `"FG"`.

Then, when you do `a = set('FG')`, you define a set using an iterable, but in that case the iterable is not a list but a string. The set function will find all unique elements in the specified iterable, so in that case it will find all unique characters in the given string.

If you wanted the two to output the same result, you would have to give the set function a list containing individual strings, for instance: `a = set(["FG"])`.

Answer (score 0):

When passing integers, you're passing it in the form of a list.

```
>>>a=set([1,2,3])
>>>print(a)
{1,2,3}
```

Whereas you're not passing the string in list,

```
>>>a=set('FG')
>>>print(a)
{'F','G'}
```

so python interprets both of them differently.

If you pass the string as a list, the result would be similar to that of integer.

```
>>> a=set(['FG'])
>>> print(a)
{'FG'}
```

**set() takes iterables as input.**

Comment: Therefore  any parameter passed to set() is always  treated as an Iterable. It seems to me then that the type String is the only case where the behavior is different

Answer (score 0):

The `set` constructor takes an `iterable` and adds each element of the iterable object to the set. So when you construct the set with the iterable list `[1,2,3]`, you naturally end up with `{1, 2, 3}`.

A string is actually *iterable*:

```
for i in 'abc':
    print(i)
```

Prints:

```
a
b
c
```

Iterating over a string returns each character of the string for each iteration. So when you construct a set with a string (which you can do because it is an iterable), you end up with a set where each character becomes a separate member of the set:

```
set('FG') -> {'F', 'G'}
```

But when you are creating a set by using a *literal* and not invoking a *constructor*, as in `{'FG'}`, you are just creating a set with a single member `'FG'`.